# Different types of models into a django field

Tags: django, django-models

Is there an option to create a field that can contain a list of different types of other models?
For example we have 3 models (Man,Woman,Child), and a field that can containt a list of them?
So that i could for example do something like Human.var.add(Woman), Human.var.add(Man), Human.var.add(Child).

- *Some sort of a list / dict as a field could also work*

(and this field should containt many of them, var containt many of them).

Real example:

```
class Man(models.Model):
    name = models.Cha....
    age = models.Inte.....

class Woman(models.Model):
    name = models.Cha....
    age = models.Inte.....

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.Cha....
    age = models.Inte.....


class Family(models.Model):
    people = *This field should take a list of Man, Woman Child, or a few of each*
```

Comment: I guess you can solve it with foreign key and inheritance. Please, post a real sample an I will try to fix your models to match requirements.

Comment: @daniherrera Added a real example, Thank you, I've found some sort of a solution after digging in the docks, and i've found JSONField, but maybe there's a better option.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of store people on family, the canonical design is to reference family from people:

```py
from django.db import models
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager


class Family(models.Model):
    pass

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family, related_name="people", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    objects = InheritanceManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Man(Person): # <--- Important part, inheritance
    pass # be free to extend subclasses with more fields

class Woman(Person):
    pass

class Child(Person):
    pass
```

Notice, for my convenience, I use [inheritance manager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) from `django-model-utils`. But it's not mandatory if you don't need to select subclasses.

Here creating people and getting people from a family:

```py
from people.models import Family, Man, Woman, Child

# first, we create a family
family=Family.objects.create()

# then, we assign people to the family
man=Man.objects.create(name="Daddy Pig", age=50, family=family)
woman=Woman.objects.create(name="Mummy Pig", age=50, family=family)
child=Child.objects.create(name="George", age=5, family=family)

# finally, we ask for family people. Here the more beautiful part:
family.people.select_subclasses()
```

Result:

```
<InheritanceQuerySet [<Man: Daddy Pig>, <Woman: Mummy Pig>, <Child: George>]>
```

Also take a look to [Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) because is related with this topic.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, ufortunately this wont fit, my fault, in the example i should have explaind that there are different fields in different classes, meaning "Child" for. example. may not have age field

Comment: @SlavaBugz, this is the reason about to write good questions. Btw, just move fields from supertyoe to subtypes. This is the way. My answer is right.

Comment: Any case, change the sample and let me know to change the answer.